# Any good way to use javax.mail (jakarta.mail) with MS Graph API?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, jakarta-mail

Currently we have a lot of legacy code working with outlook.office365.com via javax.mail abstractions. I.E. when we request a store it will be `javax.mail.Store`, when we are working with message - it will be `javax.mail.Message`.

```
final javax.mail.Store mailStore = session.getStore(protocol);
```

And there is a lot of code, relying on javax.mail abstraction.

But when working with MS Graph API what returned from API SDK is com.microsoft.graph.models.Message, etc., which is not compatible with the legacy code.

Is there any way to use MS graph API, but still keep javax.Mail (or jakarta.mail) abstractions? Maybe without MS java graph SDK libraries?

Comment: Just use the full class name with package.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. There is no problem in having two Message classes from different packages in same file. The problem is that all the logic in our legacy app wants javax.mail.* classes, which are absent in Microsoft Graph SDK for java. Since javax.mail.* is kind of universal classes (abstraction), I thought there should be a good way to call MS Graph and still be on javax.mail.*

Comment: This topic is being discussed on: [Graph API implementation for Jakarta Mail](https://www.eclipse.org/lists/angus-dev/msg00003.html).  Once it closes I can add an answer.  For sure it seems there is interest in this sort of thing.

Comment: Hi @jmehrens! It seems like Angus is not going to include more providers in Angus Mail. Will your team publish library independently? Can I ask if there is a source code of it, or at least its name? Thanks!

Comment: @EugeneS The thread on the angus-dev is the only contact I have.  I'm on the Angus team not the team that built graph API provider.  I'll update that email thread.